# Scala API: view IndexedSeq[T] as Map[Int, T]

Tags: scala

Simply speaking, is there a way in Scala collections library which would provide map-like view for indexed sequence, using indices as keys?

I have following trait (limit on 16 elems is intended and enforced by external API)

```
trait Container[T >: Null]
{
    private val ElemsLimit = 16 // block's meta is 4-bit
    private var table: Seq[T] = null

    protected def register(elems: (Int, T)*)(implicit manifest: Manifest[T]) =
    {
        if (table != null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Already initialized")
        val array = Array.fill[T](ElemsLimit)(null)
        elems foreach { el => array(el._1) = el._2 }
        table = array
    }

    def elem(idx: Int) = table(idx)
    def allElems = table.zipWithIndex.filter(_  != null) // some mapView instead of zipWithIndex
}
```

I know that I can construct immutable map, and frankly speaking it will work just fine for my purposes. I can also write MapView for this myself. Though I'm really interested if there's existing solution somewhere. Or, maybe, there's array-backed immutable map which I missed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```scala
IndexedSeq("A", "B").zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).toMap
```

Result will be `Map[Int,String] = Map(0 -> A, 1 -> B)`

Alternative with `foldLeft` could be:

```scala
IndexedSeq("A", "B").foldLeft(0 -> Map.empty[Int,String]) {
  case ((i, m), v) => i+1 -> (m + (i -> v)) // next state is
  // incremented index & updated map
}._2 // keep only the built map, not the last processed index
```

Comment: I search for a 'view' solution, i.e. the one that doesn't create unnecessary full copy. If I needed zipWithIndex then I would just do so.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is modification of the resulting map, e.g. removing or adding an element. How should that behave? For a simple optional `get` method, you may try lift:

```
val xs = "hallo".toVector
val m = xs.lift
m(-1) // None
m(1)  // Some('a')
```

Otherwise you need to write your own wrapper and decide how to deal with modifications. E.g.

```
class IndexMap[A](peer: IndexedSeq[A]) extends collection.immutable.Map[Int, A] {
  private def unsupported(name: String): Nothing = 
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(name)

  def +[B1 >: A](kv: (Int, B1)): collection.immutable.Map[Int, B1] = 
    unsupported("+")

  def -(key: Int): collection.immutable.Map[Int, A] = unsupported("-")

  def get(key: Int): Option[A] = if (key < 0 || key >= peer.size) None 
    else Some(peer(key))

  def iterator: Iterator[(Int, A)] = peer.zipWithIndex.iterator.map(_.swap)
}

val im = new IndexMap(xs)

im.get(-1)  // None
im.get(1)   // Some('a')
```

---

> Or, maybe, there's array-backed immutable map which I missed.

As far as I know, `HashMap` (default immutable map implementation) uses arrays already, although perhaps not as efficient as a plain indexed seq:

```
val hm = xs.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)(collection.breakOut): Map[Int, Char]
val ht = hm.asInstanceOf[collection.immutable.HashMap.HashTrieMap[_, _]]
val mm = ht.getClass.getMethod("elems")
mm.setAccessible(true)
val arr = mm.invoke(ht)  // Array(Map(0 -> h), Map(1 -> a), ...)
```